# After which errors should network task be restarted?

Tags: ios, networking, nsurlsession

Right now I’m trying to build the networking system for my app. I want my networking operations to have the ability to retry themselves after network failure. That’s what Apple is saying about such behavior ([Designing for Real-World Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WhyNetworkingIsHard/WhyNetworkingIsHard.html)):

> For requests made at the user’s behest:
>
> Always attempt to make a connection. Do not attempt to guess whether network service is available, and do not cache that determination.
>   If a connection fails, use the SCNetworkReachability API to help diagnose the cause of the failure. Then:
>
> - If the connection failed because of a transient error, try making the connection again.
> - If the connection failed because the host is unreachable, wait for the SCNetworkReachability API to call your registered callback. When the host becomes reachable again, your app should retry the connection attempt automatically without user intervention (unless the user has taken some action to cancel the request, such as closing the browser window or clicking a cancel button).

I implemented this functionality successfully, but I’m having troubles deciding what «a transient error» actually is.

Right now I’m retrying a task after receiving `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet`, `NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost`, `NSURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff`, `NSURLErrorCallIsActive`, `NSURLErrorDataNotAllowed` or `NSURLErrorTimedOut` and HTTP status code in range of 500…599, but I’m not sure if those are enough.

I would be very happy to hear an advice from more experienced developers who also use the retrying behavior. How do you decide when to retry the task, and when to not?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

**NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost**: returned after a transient error.  Try again immediately or after a short delay.

**NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet**: returned when there's no connection.  Wait for reachability to change before trying again.

**NSURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff**: returned when you're on a non-home cellular connection with data roaming off.  Wait for reachability to change before trying again.

**NSURLErrorCallIsActive**: returned when the user is talking on the phone on a network that doesn't support simultaneous voice and data.  Wait for reachability to change before trying again.

**NSURLErrorDataNotAllowed**: returned only when you've explicitly said that your requests shouldn't happen over cellular and the user is not on Wi-Fi.  Wait for reachability to change before trying again.

**NSURLErrorTimedOut**: returned when a connection attempt times out waiting for an initial response from the server.  Possibly a transient network error.  Try again immediately, but limit the number of tries to a small number before treating the network as down and waiting for reachability to change before trying again.  Possibly begin a reachability check and try the request again in parallel.

Server errors are unlikely to be caused by network failures, and are also unlikely to change on an immediate retry.  The way you should handle these depends on your app, but might involve storing the data and trying again after a period of time, telling the user that the server is broken (if the user might be able to do something about it), automatically sending a trouble ticket to your server team, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed summary!

Comment: Thanks for making me look at it again.  The last paragraph was kind of confusing.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

NSURLErrorCallIsActive shouldn't happen anymore on recent devices (that was for devices that couldn't access data while you were in a phone call); if it happens you could retry say every 5 seconds until the user hangs up.

NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet, NSURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff, NSURLErrorDataNotAllowed probably need some user action. Retrying is pointless unless you tell the user first.

NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost, NSURLErrorTimedOut, and range 500-599 you can retry, but not too often. "Connection Lost" should either change to "not connected" or should work when you retry. Consider that "Timed Out" usually takes a long time anyway (default 60 seconds) so you only want to retry if it is a background operation. 500's may be errors in your code. Or they may be things that require rebooting the server, so retry after a generous time.

Comment: On Verizon and Sprint, AFAIK, even current devices can't access data while you're on a call (unless you're on LTE and VoLTE is enabled on that cell site).

Comment: For Sprint users with old SIM cards, iPhones earlier than iPhone 8 or so *still* don't support VoLTE, FYI.  However, this will become rarer soon.  By January 1, Sprint is requiring everyone to replace their old SIMs with new T-Mobile SIM cards (or lose 3G fallback).  After that, the only time you'll see this (ignoring users who don't turn on VoLTE) is while on a legacy 3G network, which will go away in February (AT&T), April (T-Mobile/migrated Sprint), and December (Verizon) of 2022, which leaves people who don't turn on VoLTE, at least in the U.S.  Other countries will probably do similarly.